# Save image in nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have a scenario where I need to save an image from the `<Image />` tag to the local file. The code does save the image to the file but i get an empty image, I know it's sound simple but I am new to NS and couldn't find anything on google, maybe someone knows why?

**XML:**

```
<page>
   <image src="pic.png" id="img"/>
</page>
```

**JS:**

```
let img       = page.getViewById("img");
let path      = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.documents().path, "pic.png");    
let src       = ImageSource.fromNativeSource(img);
let saved     = src.saveToFile(path, "png");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might be getting empty image because of saving image before it is fully loaded. try saving image after it is fully loaded as shown in below snippet.

To save image after it's load we are using `loaded` event and `isLoading` property of the Image.

**XML:**

```
<page>
   <image src="pic.png" loaded="onImageLoaded" id="img"/>
</page>
```

**TS:**

```
onImageLoaded(args) {
    console.log(args.eventName);
    console.log(args.object);

    var img = args.object;

    console.log("img.isLoading: " + img.isLoading);
    console.log("img.isLoaded: " + img.isLoaded);
    if(img.isLoading){

        img.on("isLoadingChange", function (args) {
            console.log("isloading",args.value);
            console.log("isloaded",args.object.isLoaded);
            let img       = args.object;
            let path      = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.documents().path, "pic.png");    
            let src       = ImageSource.fromNativeSource(img);
            let saved     = src.saveToFile(path, "png");
        });
    }else if(!img.isLoading&&img.isLoaded){
        let path      = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.documents().path, "pic.png");    
        let src       = ImageSource.fromNativeSource(img);
        let saved     = src.saveToFile(path, "png");
    }else{
        console.log("image loading failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: also don't forget check for the case when image loading finished and it is not successful load.